# From the information given below- prove that Z = 4561

Tags: formation-of-numbers

If-

ONE * THREE * FIVE = 225

NINE * SEVEN + TWELVE = X

225 + X = Y

10,18,32,56,93,146,?

? + Y = Z

**Prove that, Z = 4561**

Answer (score 5):

ONE * THREE * FIVE = 225

> $LHS$
>  $= ONE * THREE * FIVE$ 
>  $= (one*one)* (three*three)*(five*five)$
>  $= (1*1)*(3*3)*(5*5)$
>  $= 1*9*25$
>  $= 225$
>  $= RHS$

NINE * SEVEN + TWELVE = X

> $X= NINE * SEVEN + TWELVE$
> $= (nine*nine)*(seven*seven) + (twelve*twelve)$
> $= (9*9)*(7*7) + (12*12)$
> $= 81*49 + 144$
> $= 3969 + 144$
> $= 4113$

225 + X = Y

> $Y= 225 + X = 225+4113 = 4338$

10,18,32,56,93,146,?

> $ 10, 18, 32, 56, 93, 146, 223 [?=223]$
> $f(x) = (2n^6 – 39n^5 + 290n^4 – 825n^3 +1688n^2 + 324n + 2160) /360$

? + Y = Z

> $Z = ? + Y= 223+4338= 4561$

From this we can say that,

> $Z = 4561$

Comment: Hmf smarty pants...

Comment: So, in essence, invent a plausible solution for the first line, do random math to acquire an Y, figure out the required ’?’, and fit an arbitrary polynomial to that value. Cheeky. I like it. +1